# rolling water/gas outage?

Tags: word-request

I was reading about [rolling blackout](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_Blackout) and if I understand correctly it's when the electric utility company intentinally cuts out a region electricity like it's rationed and takes turn providing different regions with electricity by hour for example, because the demand for electricity is more than what it can supply.

What would be some phrases to describe the same occassion for water and gas?

Comment: I haven't heard of this being done for water or natural gas service, but I think it would be called the same thing (a rolling outage). I haven't heard "rolling blackout" used here (western US).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For electrical power

> rolling blackouts

is the phrase used for electricity **rationing**.  Other resources can also be rationed

> water rationing
>   gas rationing
>   gasoline rationing

where each individual consumer is only allowed a specific amount of the resource.

Because of the nature of the infrastructure for water and gas, it is not as easy to divert these resources as it is to divert electricity.  It usually has to occur much further "upstream". Some of the challenges and comparison between electrical and water utility "smartness" can be found [here](http://www.worldwatertechnorthamerica.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/FATHOM-Whitepaper-Smart-grid-water-vs-electricity.pdf).